# SQL Server : delete maximal value over multiply PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like delete from my table duplicity over primary key only there where is maximum number of different column

```
Column1PK Column2    Column3    Column4
----------------------------------------
Dog       468        JOURNALING     1
Dog       466        JOURNALING     2
Cat       268        TRAVELING      1
Cat       366        TRAVELING      2
Cat       166        TRAVELING      3
...        ..         ..     


Column1PK  Column2     Column3
-----------------------------------
Dog        468         JOURNALING
Cat        366         TRAVELING
..         ..          ..
```

My code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
       [Column1PK], [Column2], [Column3],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1PK] ORDER BY [Column1PK])
   FROM 
       [dbo].[table] 
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1 and MAX[Column2]
```

My other idea is:

```
Column1PK  Column3    
----------------------
Dog468     JOURNALING    
Dog466     JOURNALING     
Cat268     TRAVELING      
Cat366     TRAVELING     
Cat166     TRAVELING


Column1PK  Column3       
-------------------------
Dog466     JOURNALING          
Cat366     TRAVELING
```

Code:

```
delete from table 
where Column1PK RIGHT (LEN(MAXColumn1PK))
```

Thanks for opinions how delete max value over multiple PK

Comment: select Column1PK, max(Column2) from table
group by Column1PK; MY NEXT IDEA

Comment: I'm confused.  Primary keys are always unique.

Comment: Primary keys are always unique.. I Know but after SSIS which take +100 csv. and insert that into 1 table.. CSVs have same PK..

Comment: if you want to delete the value greater user ORDER BY ASC otherwise use ORDER BY DESC in part row_number()

Comment: By definition your table does NOT have duplicate primary keys. The only way this is possible is if you don't actually have a primary key on the table.

Answer (score 0):

delete the minor

```
DELETE A
(
   SELECT 
       [Column1PK], [Column2], [Column3],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1PK] ORDER BY [Column1PK] DESC)
   FROM 
       [dbo].[table] 
) A
WHERE RN > 1
```

Delete the largest

```
DELETE A
(
   SELECT 
       [Column1PK], [Column2], [Column3],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1PK] ORDER BY [Column1PK] ASC)
   FROM 
       [dbo].[table] 
) A
WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to remove only the duplicates with the highest value, you can use exists. That would look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A AS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_A AS A2
               WHERE A2.Column1PK = A.Column1PK
                 AND A2?? < A.??)
```